# Jquery Drag Sort order Call a function or API when change sort order (need help)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a pre-written code I want to change it. I don't understand what the problem is.
I want to call an API when changing sort order of li. Here is the code:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert:true
    });

    $( "#dragable" ). draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert:"invalid"
    });

       $("#sortable").bind( "sortstop", function (event, ui){

       var currentItem = ui.item;
       var currentPosition = $('#sortable li').index(currentItem) ;
       var callApi = true;
       var Id = currentItem[0].id;
       var html = Id.split('_')[1];
       if( currentPosition == sortOrder[html])
         {

        callApi=false;

            }
           sortOrder[html] = currentPosition;


          if(callApi)
          {

           buyer=new BHBuyer();
           buyer.updateSortOrder(html,currentPosition);
           }

    });


    $("ul, li").disableSelection();

    });
```

When I run this it gave me this error *"Uncaught ReferenceError: sortOrder is not defined"*
Can any one help?
Or is their any alternative way to fix this :S?

Comment: Well, the variable "sortOrder" doesn't appear to be defined, so the error is not surprising. What do you expect "sortOrder" to be?

Comment: well my goal is to call the Fucntion/API when sort order in Li is Changes. if i drag the li and dint change the sort order it should not call the API/function. where should i set the sortOder in the code? i did _var sortOrder = '0';_ that stops the error but dont call the API.  where should i call it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize sortOrder with `var sortOrder = new Object();`. This have to be done on the global code, not inside the function.

Also change

```
if( currentPosition == sortOrder[html])
```

to

```
if (sortOrder[html] && currentPosition == sortOrder[html])
```

which will check if `sortOrder[html]` is defined before comparing